# Getting latest Directory from FTP

Tags: python, ftp

I have a number of directories in my ftp and my goal is to retrieve the most recently created one and download it.

I am attempting to sort the dates of the directories into a list and then work out what one is the most recent. This is my code so far:

```
import ftplib


ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.myftp.com')
ftp.login('USER', 'PASS') 

ftp.cwd('Current Dir')

my_dir = ftp.nlst()

empty = []

for e in my_dir:
    a = ftp.sendcmd('MDTM ' + e)
    empty.append(a)
```

However, when i run this code i get an error telling me that `The system cannot find the file specified.` even though if i print `my_dir` i can see all of the Directories.

I am not even sure if this is the right way to go about finding the latest Directory in my ftp so any help would be much appreciated. :)

EDIT:

Here is another attempt i have made but still no luck. I can't work out why this second one throws an error:

```
import ftplib, os

#Login
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.myftp.com')
ftp.login('USER', 'PASS') 

#Change to my directory
ftp.cwd('Current Dir')

my_dir = ftp.nlst()

#Get latest directory
latest_directory = max(my_dir, key = os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: What is `my_lists` in this situation?

Comment: Sorry, that was mistake it should have been my_dir. I have corrected the error.

Comment: As far as I know MDTM does not work on directories but only files themselves. Thus when you try to execute the command on a directory structure it will throw an exception that it can't find the specified file, specifically a 550 I believe.

Comment: Thankyou very much, that makes lot of sense now i think about it. I am new to Python and am just finding my way around. Do you know how to retrieve data from the Directories and not just files?